# Add new object property to JSON response in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm trying to add a new object property to my JSON response.

My sample JSON response

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xyz"
    }]
}
```

After getting the response need to add new object property(show) to the same JSON response

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xyz",
        "show": false
    }]
}
```

This is my sample code

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    @Component({
      templateUrl:'./electronics.html'
    })
    export class electronicsComponent{
      productListElectronics={};
        productListElectronicResponse: Object;
        error:Object;
        constructor(private http: Http) {
          this.productListElectronicResponse={};
            this.error={};
            http.get('../json/electronics/electronics.json').map((res: Response) =>res.json()).subscribe(res =>
              {

                for(var i = 0; i <= res['products'].length; i++){
                    res['products'][i].show=false;
                  }
                  console.log(res);
           }, error => this.error = error );
      }
    }
```

But console keeps on throwing the following error:

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of undefined
>     at SafeSubscriber.http.get.map.subscribe._this.error [as _next] (products.component.ts:22)
>     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:238)
>     at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:190)
>     at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
>     at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
>     at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:80)
>     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:104)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
> ```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line in question, wait for it to get there, then example values such as `i` or `res['products'][i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= res['products'].length; i++)
```

It should be

```
for(var i = 0; i <res['products'].length; i++)
```

:)

https://jsfiddle.net/rt6LjvLa/

Comment: It would be so nice if there was a close reason for typos. Oh, wait a minute, there is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for traversing your array of objects:

```
for(var key in res['products']){

    res['products'][key].show=false;

}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/echonax/dm1d0vyw/

Comment: Using `for...in` for iterating over an array is generally frowned on.

Comment: @torazaburo if the keys are not indexes, how else are you going to traverse the object?

Comment: With an array, the keys are (almost always) indexes.

Comment: @torazaburo ah now I see that in will also traverse the prototype keys. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility 1:**

Remove `=` from `<=` from `for` loop else it would run one more time for undefined object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < res['products'].length; i++){
    res['products'][i].show=false;
}
```

**It above solution does not work then try below Possibility 2**

I suspect `res['products']` returns an `json array`.

**Run below lines of code and attach your result here:**

```
console.log(res['products'])
for(var i = 0; i <= res['products'].length; i++){
    console.log(res['products'][i]);
    res['products'][i].show=false;
}
```